# How can I write well formatted code in React Native?

Tags: react-native, code-formatting

I'm new in React Native. I want to write well formatted code so I can manage big apps easily and I can change existing code with new change.

Right now I'm putting all component in single block, so I'm confused when I want to change in that.

I have made registration screen as below. My code messed up and looks so distorted. Please help me how can I manage my code to good fragments way.

```
import LoginScreen from './Login';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';

import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  Image,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
} from 'react-native';

class RegistrationScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    textInputTexts: {
      username: '',
      password: '',
      email: '',
      phoneno: '',
    },
    validFlags: {
      username: false,
      password: false,
      email: false,
      phoneno: false,
    },
  };

  validateEmail = text => {
    console.log(text);
    let reg = /^([\w.%+-]+)@([\w-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})$/i;
    console.log(reg.test(text));

    if (reg.test(text) === false) {
      console.log('Email is Not Correct');
      return false;
    } else {
      console.log('Email is Correct');
      return true;
    }
  };

  validatePassword = text => {
    console.log(text);
    var passRegex = new RegExp(
      '^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.{8,})',
    );

    console.log(passRegex.test(text));

    if (passRegex.test(text) === false) {
      console.log('Password is Not Valid');
      return false;
    } else {
      console.log('Password is Correct');
      return true;
    }
  };

  validateUsername = text => {
    console.log(text);
    var usernameRegex = new RegExp('(?=.*[a-fA-F])(?=.{5,})');

    console.log(usernameRegex.test(text));

    if (usernameRegex.test(text) === false) {
      console.log('Username is Not Valid');
      return false;
    } else {
      console.log('Username is Correct');
      return true;
    }
  };

  textInputTextChanged = (key, value) => {
    var valid = false;
    if (key === 'username') {
      valid = this.validateUsername(value);
    } else if (key === 'password') {
      valid = this.validatePassword(value);
    } else if (key === 'email') {
      valid = this.validateEmail(value);
    } else if (key === 'phoneno') {
      if (value.length === 10) {
        valid = true;
      }
    }
    if (valid) {
      console.log('Input is valid');
    } else {
      console.log('Input is not valid');
    }
    //this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.textInputTexts, {[key]: value}));
    this.setState({
      textInputTexts: {...this.state.textInputTexts, [key]: value},
      validFlags: {...this.state.validFlags, [key]: valid},
    });
    //console.log(this.state);
  };

  signUp = () => {
    const {validFlags} = this.state;
    console.log('Sign up click');

    if (
      validFlags.username &&
      validFlags.password &&
      validFlags.email &&
      validFlags.phoneno
    ) {
      // navigate to Login screen
      console.log('Go to login screen');

      this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginScreen');
    }
  };
  render() {
    const {validFlags} = this.state; // this is for constant parameter of this.state to avoid writing this.state.validFlags
    console.log(this.state);
    const errorImage = (
      <Image
        source={require('./../images/error-icon.png')}
        style={styles.errorImageStyle}
      />
    );
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView>
          <View>
            <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.textInput}
                placeholder="Username"
                autoCapitalize="none"
                placeholderTextColor="#a7a7a7"
                onChangeText={value =>
                  this.textInputTextChanged('username', value)
                }
              />
              {!validFlags.username && errorImage}
            </View>
            {!validFlags.username && (
              <Text style={styles.errorLabelStyle}>
                Username must contain 5 alphabets
              </Text>
            )}
            <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.textInput}
                placeholder="Password"
                autoCapitalize="none"
                placeholderTextColor="#a7a7a7"
                secureTextEntry={true}
                onChangeText={value =>
                  this.textInputTextChanged('password', value)
                }
              />
              {!validFlags.password && errorImage}
            </View>
            {!validFlags.password && (
              <Text style={styles.errorLabelStyle}>
                Password must contain 8 characters with atleast one special
                character, Capital and small characters and numbers
              </Text>
            )}
            <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.textInput}
                placeholder="Email Id"
                autoCapitalize="none"
                placeholderTextColor="#a7a7a7"
                onChangeText={value =>
                  this.textInputTextChanged('email', value)
                }
              />
              {!validFlags.email && errorImage}
            </View>
            {!validFlags.email && (
              <Text style={styles.errorLabelStyle}>
                Email text should be valid email id
              </Text>
            )}
            <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.textInput}
                placeholder="Phone No."
                autoCapitalize="none"
                placeholderTextColor="#a7a7a7"
                keyboardType="number-pad"
                onChangeText={value =>
                  this.textInputTextChanged('phoneno', value)
                }
              />
              {!validFlags.phoneno && errorImage}
            </View>
            {!validFlags.phoneno && (
              <Text style={styles.errorLabelStyle}>
                Phone number must contain 10 digits
              </Text>
            )}
            <Button title="Sign Up" onPress={this.signUp} />
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    width: 300,
    paddingTop: 300,
  },
  textInput: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#E2E2E2',
    marginTop: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    padding: 8,
    color: 'black',
    borderRadius: 10,
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
  textInputContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  errorImageStyle: {
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
  },
  errorLabelStyle: {
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
    color: 'red',
    paddingLeft: 8,
    marginBottom: 10,
    fontSize: 12,
  },
});

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    RegistrationScreen: {
      screen: RegistrationScreen,
    },
    LoginScreen: {
      screen: LoginScreen,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'LoginScreen',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      title: 'App',
    },
  },
);

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Comment: Some sugestions are as follows : 1 Create styles as a common seperate file
2 : Reusable bolcks can be added in seperate Component 3: Choose a better directory structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best advantages of using react-native is its component driven. You can follow the some of the below mentioned things,

- Have separate file for navigation, I see `createStackNavigator` and other things in registration page, its not good, it must be put in different file.
- Separate out styles in different file, each component must have a corresponding style file from where it refers too.
- Write as much re-usable components as possible, for ex in your case,

  ```
  <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
    <TextInput
       style={styles.textInput}
       placeholder="Email Id"
       autoCapitalize="none"
       placeholderTextColor="#a7a7a7"
       onChangeText={value =>
          this.textInputTextChanged('email', value)
       }
     />
     {!validFlags.email && errorImage}
  </View>
  ```

Is repeated a lot of times, make it as a separate component and pass only the required props to it, let the common things remain as it is.

- For whole application architecture point of view use [redux](https://redux.js.org/)
- Use [Prettier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettier) for code formatting.